# Is there a way to specify the length of a request with post method?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping the economic calendar table from investing.com. I am using Beautiful soup and requests libraries. I do a query with post method and I can't seem to find a way to get a data response that contains more than 200 rows from the table.

If you look at the network traffic when updating the table filters, you can see that there is a "getCalendarFilteredData" request. I based the post request on this. I have tried changing the header and query parameters shown below in the code, but I can not figure this out. I could use some help. This is what I have:

```py
url = 'https://in.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                        '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
          "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
          }

query = {
            "country[]": [17, 25, 6, 37, 5, 72, 22, 39, 35, 4],
            "importance[]": [1, 2, 3],
            "dateFrom": start_date,
            "dateTo": current_date,
            "timeZone": 58,
        }
```

And for the request:

```py
with requests.Session() as s:
    try:
        web = s.post(url, headers=header, data=query)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(web.json()['data'], 'html.parser')
        rows = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'js-event-item'})
```

After inserting the data into a pandas data frame I get this size no matter what the parameters are.

[200 rows x 7 columns]

The number of rows should be significantly larger as I am trying to scrape data from the early 2000's. Any tips on how to progress?

Comment: Maybe is intended by the website API, check their documentation.

Comment: At first I thought that too!! But this website does not offer an API, hence why I am scraping the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit to the query, you can see it in  "getCalendarFilteredData" response.

```
params:{
limit: "0,200"
}
```

You can get the next set by sending `params:{"limit_from":2)`
You can see it in getCalendarFilteredData request if you look at the form data. I've tested and was able to get different data by incrementing the limit_from parameter by 1 each time.

Comment: Yes! I tried that but I did not succeed. For testing purposes I set the parameter to `400,200` but got the same data as for `0,200`. Did you try?

Comment: You are correct. it's actually `params:{"limit_from": 2}`. i've edited the answer